# GitHub merging is blocked because all commits have to be signed, but they are signed

Tags: github

My pull requests are saying `The base branch requires all commits to be signed`:

[image: blocked]

But they are signed and `Verified`:

[image: verified]

Why would it block the pull request?

Comment: We ran into the same scenario today while trying to merge from `develop` into `master`: All merge commits of other branches on develop appear Verified, all other non-squashed commits appear without any tag, but that should be fine, right? DCO shows a green mark so all signatures are there... This GitHub ticket seems related to our issue https://github.com/dcoapp/app/issues/123, but the solution suggested seems to be "fix your unverified commits", and we don't have any... Any clues?